# Importing Wheelnav.js into Angular 2 / 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm-install, wheelnav.js

I'm trying to find a decent circular menu with submenu for days.
I really like the library of wheelnav.js quite well.

Now I tried to integrate this into my Angular 4 Project, but without success.
I'm missing a little the understanding how I should do that.

I will briefly describe my approach to an example project.

1. `npm install wheelnav --save -dev`
2. `npm install raphael --save -dev`
3. `npm install @types/raphael --save -dev`

I have created a new directory which looks like this.
...ts file

```
import { Component,} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'ch-par-vaporizer',
  templateUrl: './par-vaporizer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./par-vaporizer.component.css']
})

export class ParVaporizerComponent {

twheel = require('../../../node_modules/wheelnav/js/dist/wheelnav.js');
twheeln:any;
  constructor() {
    this.twheeln = new this.twheel.wheelnav('wheelDiv');
    console.log(this.twheeln);
    this.twheeln.createWheel("test");
    console.log(this.twheeln);

   }
}
```

If I want to output the object in the console, I get only errors like **"this.twhell is not a constructor"**.
I have already tested several possibilities, but come to no solution.

I would be glad if you could help me with the integration. 
Am still something new with Angular.

Many Thanks

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are just a few steps you have to do to utilize Wheelnav in your Angular application.

1. Add the javascript resources (wheelnav and raphael) to the head tag of your application (index.html)
2. Add a type definition in your application to make wheelnav visible

   ```
   declare var wheelnav: any;
   ```
3. Add some code to create a wheel

   ```
   let wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
   wheel.initWheel(["init", "create", "navigate", "refresh"]);
   wheel.createWheel();
   ```

I have made a little Stackblitz example that shows what to do:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a54edh

Just have a look at the app.component.ts and the template.

Answer (score 0):

I have also integrated it into the angular-cli.

```
{
  "project": {
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "ch",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js",
        "../node_modules/wheelnav/js/dist/raphael.min.js",
        "../node_modules/wheelnav/js/dist/raphael.icons.min.js",
        "../node_modules/wheelnav/js/dist/wheelnav.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "component": {
      "spec": true,
      "inlineStyle": false,
      "inlineTemplate": false
    }
  }
}
```